# How to get the updated state in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you please tell me how can I update the states of prevMessages and messages in my function? Now i get error "cannot get id of undefined".

Error in this line: `const msgID = prevMessages.length ? parseInt(prevMessages[0].id) : parseInt(messages[0].id);`

```
const debounce = (func, wait) => {
        let timeout;
        return (() => {
            if (timeout) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
            timeout = setTimeout(() => func(), wait)
        })();
    }

    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        if(e.target.scrollTop < 1) {
            const msgID = prevMessages.length ? parseInt(prevMessages[0].id) : parseInt(messages[0].id);
            console.log(msgID);
            socket.emit('getPrevMessages', {roomId, msgID});
            //e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }

    const debouncedChangeHandler = useCallback((e) => debounce(() => changeHandler(e), 250),[]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are `prevMessages` and `messages`?

Comment: Try this: `const msgID = prevMessages.length ? parseInt(prevMessages[0].id) : messages.length ? parseInt(messages[0].id) : 'notFound';`

Comment: prevMessages = useState() => Array